# Use anaconda environment without activate? (e.g. in Crontab)

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, uwsgi, miniconda

Being reading this

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html

Is it possible to run a conda python directly without having to `source activate xxx`?

In VirtualEnv, you can find the exact location of the python executable and run something like this

`./path/to/my/venv/bin/python xxx.py`

Then xxx.py will be executed with environment on. It's handy to write one-linders in Crontab.

Could I do the same with anaconda/miniconda environments?

I've been trying this on Centos 6.5, system has python 2.5 which is too old.

I installed python 2.7 with miniconda, now I pip installed uWSGI, when executing it *directly* says

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

But when execute it under conda env it works as expected.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `conda` is on your path:

`source activate <env name> && python xxx.py && source deactivate`

If `conda` isn't on your path but is installed:

`source /path/to/conda/bin/activate /path/to/desired/env_name/ && python xxx.py && source deactivate`

Comment: This works perfectly for me in my crontab: 0 1 * * * source /path/to/conda/bin/activate /path/to/desired/env_name/ && python /path/to/script/xxx.py && source deactivate

Comment: this is great,  the details is fantastic. Thank you

Comment: I could not get this to work exactly like that on my current conda version (4.9.1). The activate script did not seem to accept the environment name parameter. I had to do `source /path/to/activate && conda activate /path/to/env_name && ...`

Comment: `conda` provide `conda run` command since v3.6 and I think it should be the best solution. `conda run` will setup the environment for you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `conda run` (since v3.6) to use a specified environemnt to run your command without activating the environment. For example

```bash
# run scripts or commands against specific environment
conda run -n myenv python start_server.py

# or run an python interactively 
conda run -n myenv --no-capture-output python
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can do exactly the same as in venv in miniconda. 
If path_to_miniconda is your installation dir of miniconda, then

/path_to_miniconda/envs/name_of_env/bin/python xxx.py

should work.

Comment: That is true for the root conda environment, but the posters question asked about environments in general.  For non-root environments, conda packages can install scripts to be run when an environment gets "turned on" with activate/deactivate.  As such, it's best to actually activate the environment before trying to use it