# How to activate an anaconda environment within a Python script on a remote machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, os.system

I am currently trying to find a way to activate an anaconda environment within a Python script that is running on a remote server. I have found the following similar questions on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275308/how-do-you-activate-an-anaconda-environment-within-a-python-script), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982273/use-anaconda-environment-without-activate-e-g-in-crontab), but have had no success with what they suggest. I just keep getting this simple error `sh: 1: source: not found`.From my understanding this is because the conda environment it not being found After much research, I have found no other way to do this when using a python script, but if anyone has an suggestions I would love to pass some ideas around! Thanks, in advance!

Here is the code:

```
import os 
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

value = 'activate punc2'
#os.system("cd /Users/elicobler/tiny_dancer/Testing/thrive/API_text_results")
#os.system('source root/conda3/envs/punc2/bin/activate /root/conda3/envs/punc2')
#os.system('source activate punc2')
#Popen('source activate punc2')
#subprocess.call('source', value)
subprocess.run('source root/conda3/envs/punc2/bin/activate /root/conda3/envs/punc2 && cat /var/www/html/1.22.18 - Monday - Hr 1 - Seg 1-5a65e2698c1dd07f02c25679.txt | python punctuator.py models/endquote.pcl /var/www/html/1.22.18 - Monday - Hr 1 - Seg 1-5a65e2698c1dd07f02c25679.txt && source deactivate', shell=True)
```

Comment: Actually, I think `source` itself is not found.  See my answer.

Comment: @DanFarrell Ahhhh! That is true, I forgot that it would be in a shell and not a bash! I will try this out when I get a chance later this evening.

Comment: I know it's old, but the answer is indeed that it's using '/bin/sh' instead of bash, where you need just a `.` instead of `source`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your default shell doesn't support `source`, but it's likely your system also provides bash.  Try something like this:

```
subprocess.run("bash -c 'source /root/conda3/envs/punc2/bin/activate /root/conda3/envs/punc2 && ... && source deactivate', shell=True)
```

You don't need a shell to invoke a shell, so you could probably get away with something more like

```
subprocess.run("/use/bin/env", "bash", "-c", "source /root/conda3/envs/punc2/bin/activate /root/conda3/envs/punc2 && ... && source deactivate")
```

Comment: This did the trick! Had to make a few minor changes, but got it working perfectly. Thanks for all your help!