# How can I create an environment that can be used without activation?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have Anaconda installed on my Windows machine to manage Python and its packages via [conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

I use a third party software that expects a Python 3 install (with `numpy` and `pywin32`) in `C:\Python3`. The software cannot be configured to look somewhere else for Python, nor can it be configured to activate a conda environment.

I don't want to download another Python distribution and install it in `C:\` but I want to use conda environments to manage this.

I know that I can [specify a location for the environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment) with:

```sh
conda create --prefix C:\Python3 python=3.6 numpy pywin32
```

But I would still need to activate it to use it properly, otherwise I get the warning:

> Warning:
> This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
> not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
> please see https://conda.io/activation

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37230019/1256347) suggest I `source` the activate script, but the third party software does not allow me run arbitrary commands.

How can I create an environment such that the software looking in `C:\Python3` can use it without activating the environment?